# What is the expression for the load current of the following Operational Amplifier circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier, buffer, negative-feedback, positive-feedback, 741-opamp

I have been battling to find the theoretical calculations to find the expression for the load current of the following Operational Amplifier circuit exercise I have in my "Electrical Engineering, Principles and Applications, Fifth Edition" by Alan R. Hambley? Unfortunately, there is no solution for it available.

I simulated the circuit in LtSpice, I know the input to feedback resistor ratio will result in a gain of 1 at the difference amplifier stage, with that taken into account I can figure out Iload = Vin*(Rload/Rf) and Output impedance is Rload. [Download LtSpice Circuit here.](https://gofile.io/d/LukKU0) - https://gofile.io/d/LukKU0

I'm definitely missing something with my theoretical analysis of the problem and would be really grateful if someone can assist me.

Thanks in advance
Stephan

[image: LT Spice Operation Amplifier Circuit]

Comment: Which current is the load current (place an arrow on the schematic to show it)?

Comment: What I'm trying to figure out is why would the load current be anything other than \$V_{out}/R_{load}\$?

Comment: [Howland current pump](https://d1.amobbs.com/bbs_upload782111/files_47/ourdev_694588RI0RBJ.pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so we know that the voltage at the RHS of R3 is Vout.

We know that (assuming balance) there is a virtual short between RHS of R1 & R2, so the input current is Vin/4K.

So the voltage at U1+ = U1- = Vout + Vin/2, and the voltage at U1 output is Vout + Vin.

The current into RL is (Vout+Vin-Vout)/Rf , or Vin/Rf.

Output impedance is Very High (because Vout, ideally, does not depend on RL).

Comment: Thanks Spehro, as Andy stated above it is a Howland Current Pump - https://d1.amobbs.com/bbs_upload782111/files_47/ourdev_694588RI0RBJ.pdf

Comment: Another insightful document regarding from TI [Improved Howland Current Pump](https://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/snoa474)